# Data saves only once in iteration

Tags: php, sql, loops, joomla, save

I am trying to save data. Unfortunately it saves only once per iteration, first time. After nothing happens.
Loop as itself works fine, it iterates exactly times it should.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

for($i=0; $i<=count($payments); $i++) {
        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__mytable'))->set(
            $db->quoteName('banknumber') . ' = ' . $db->quote($payments[$i]['account'])
        )->where(
            $db->quoteName('title') . ' = ' .  $db->quote($payments[$i]['name'])
        );

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

Needed to be moved inside the loop.